# Windowing in QML

Tags: qt, qml

Windowing, also known as grey-level mapping, contrast stretching, histogram modification or contrast enhancement are the terms used in medical imaging for contrast and brightness control.

Window width and window level are the parameters defining the function mapping input values to the values of pixels displayed on screen.

Here is an image showing what window width and level mean.

[image]

My problem is that I am using the QML component for contrast and brightness, but I need to display the window width and window level values.

Here are mapping tables between the brightness and window level; and contrast and window width.

```
+------------+-----+---------+-----+
|            | min | default | max |
+------------+-----+---------+-----+
| brightness |  -1 |       0 |   1 |
| WL         |   0 |     128 | 256 |
+------------+-----+---------+-----+

+----------+-----+---------+-----+
|          | min | default | max |
+----------+-----+---------+-----+
| contrast |  -1 |       0 |   1 |
| WW       |   0 |     256 |  +∞ |
+----------+-----+---------+-----+
```

The mapping function for brightness seems quite easy. However, the contrast mapping function is not linear, as the QML documentation briefly shows : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-brightnesscontrast.html#contrast-prop

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Just a guess: It might be the easiest to write your own shader with a linear contrast curve

Comment: Alternative: Analyze [the shader that is used for the effect](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtgraphicaleffects.git/tree/src/effects/shaders/brightnesscontrast.frag) and create your mapping based on it. - The magic happens in line 9 - 11

Comment: Oh nice, I stupidly did not think of looking at the qml source code. Thanks for the link.